# How to find the equation of tangent line?

Tags: calculus

Q: find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at the indicated point. Then verify your answer by sketching both the graph of $f$ and the tangent line. [PS: the point of tangency (x,y)]
$$f(x)=x^2+1 ,\quad (2,5)$$

So I got the $f'(x)=2x$
But how can I find the tangent line?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried entering "find the equation of tangent line" into a search engine?

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift ! Gotcha:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation of tangent at $(x_{0},y_{0})$ on f(x) is given by

$y=(x-x_{0})m + y_{0}$   where $m=f'(x)_{(x_{0},y_{0})}$

Can you do it now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, ILUA!!!

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line is $f'(2) = 4$ . The equation of the line is :

$$ y - 5 = f'(2)(x-2)$$

that is

$$ y = 4x - 3$$